# How to show % status or progress at UIView according to some % value?

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, uiview

How I can show the progress or % status like following image.

Here I am trying to show the % value of symptoms according to its percentage value like shown in the image.

I tried using UIView but, I don't know how to show percentage (%) data/progress like shown in the image.

Is there any solution or way to achieve this?

I still didn't Added Code.

[image: here is the image]

Comment: What is your code, it's hard to understand what your issue is without seeing it?

Comment: Take 2 view, one over the other. Give the back view grey color and front view green color. Overlap both views, once you get the %, stretch the upper view to that multiplier(backView.width*0.40(If its 40%)). You can add animation too.

Comment: use ProgressView for colour progress bar and label for showing % values

Comment: @manishsharma93 I will try your way, I will get back soon.

Comment: Sure if you need any help, Let me know. Will post code too

Comment: you can use uiprogressview with custom tint colour to achieve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do it natively, you can use a **UIProgressView.**
Create an `@Outlet` of that view and in your code, when you want to change the progress or set it, use the function

```
thenameofyouroutlet.setProgress (float, animated: bool)
```

The first parameter must be a number between *0.0* and *1.0*, where *0.0 equals 0% and 1.0 equals 100%.*

The second parameter must be `true` or `false`, `true` if you want to animate the progress, `false` if you want it to be set without animation.

Then, if you want a label that shows the progress, you can create a `UILabel` next to the bar, create your `@Outlet`, and in the same code where you set the progress, change the text of your label with `thenameofyourlabel.text`

Also, in storyboard you can set the color of the progress, and the color of the bar. [image: example]

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiprogressview
If you want more information, here is the documentation.

Comment: this works excellent way. In ans of @manishsharma93 there is issue is that ..it will work only for 1 screen (device). But this work for me.

Answer (score 1):

You Can take 2 view, one over the other.

[image: First View]

Second View on top of it with Width Constant

[image: Second View]

Now when you need to show progress, update the width constraint as,

```
self.greenViewWidthConstraint.constant = self.greyView.frame.width * 0.80 (For 80%)
```

Comment: Welcome. Happy to help :)

Comment: I will update soon again my vote. Your ans work for me only for 2 scene (device)...UI issue will come if I runt he code in diff device.